# Symfony 3 FormRegistry ->getType ('datetime')

Tags: php, datetime, symfony, formbuilder

When trying to load view,  Symfony Profiler says:

```
Could not load type "datetime"
```

I use default builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('dateCreated', 'datetime')
        ->add('dateModified', 'datetime')

    ;
}
```

How to create time fields and load view with no error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fully qualified class name is required since Symfony 3.0:

```
$builder->add('dateCreated', DatetimeType::class);    
$builder->add('dateModified', DatetimeType::class);
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @pvaitonis if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In symfony 3.0

Replace

```
'datetime'
```

With

```
 \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType::class
```

You can import the namespace